# Why it converts to T

Tags: lambda-calculus

The AND function in the lambda is:

```
and = (λ a. λ b. a b F)
```

I have following expression:

```
and T T
```

then the result will become `T` and I am asking me why?

When I do the beta reduction, then I understand, why I've got `T`:

```
(λ a . λ b . a b (λ x . λ y . y)) (λ x . λ y . x) (λ x . λ y . x)
(λ b . a b (λ x . λ y . y))[a →(λ x . λ y . x)] (λ x . λ y . x)
(λ b . (λ x . λ y . x) b (λ x . λ y . y)) (λ x . λ y . x)
((λ x . λ y . x) b (λ x . λ y . y))[b→(λ x . λ y . x)]
(λ x . λ y . x) (λ x . λ y . x) (λ x . λ y . y)
(λ y . x)[x →(λ x . λ y . x)] (λ x . λ y . y)
(λ y . (λ x . λ y . x)) (λ x . λ y . y)
(λ x . λ y . x)[y→(λ x . λ y . y)]
(λ x . λ y . x)
T
```

But when I shortened it like:

```
T T F
```

then I've got F, because:

```
T T F
T F
F
```

What am I interpreting wrong?

Comment: Why `T T F` → `T F`?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T \equiv \lambda x. \lambda y. x$, which means it is a $\lambda$-function of two arguments, returning the first one, so $(T\ T\ F)$ $\beta$-reduces to $T$, which can be shown more formally as follows.

$$T\ T\ F \equiv (\lambda x. \lambda y. x)\ T\ F \to_\beta
(\lambda y. T)\ F \to_\beta
T$$